# Best possible seat room

Tags: air-travel, united-airlines

I'm flying in economy plus with United airlines. What's the best possible seat to get with the most room? For legs, body, etc

Comment: I'm not sure this is answerable, but it's not answerable without knowing what kind of plane you will be on.

Comment: I'll check when I get home

Comment: a better question (more useful for future readers) is "how can I find out what plane I'll be on, and what the seats are like on that plane?

Comment: http://seatguru.com can give you all you need.

Comment: Also be forewarned that the aircraft can be substituted (*tail swap*, *equipment change*, etc.) at the airline's discretion, so always be prepared that you may not get exactly what you planned for in the air.